# should i start using java7 in my project?

Tags: java, java-7

i have a pure java project for infrastructure of automates tests.

should i start using java 7 in this project?

I know its a bit of a debatable question, but i would like to know what is the mainstream opinion in the java community regarding this issue.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? You should provide more specifically what issues you want to avoid or what libraries you're using that could potentially have problems with Java7.

Comment: I'm not quite aware of all the bugs discovered in java7. I know that there is a bug that happens when a loop run huge amount of times. My questions intention is to hear other projects experiences on this usse.

Comment: The bug is in Java 6 as well, the difference is that the option is on by default in Java 7 and off by default in Java 6. If you turn off this feature it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard - I don't quite agree the question is not constructive. Many companies are wondering whether to upgrade or not, including the one I'm working for.

Comment: @Bozho: It's still asking for opinions.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard many questions ask for opinions like "which is the best of these ways to go", and if there is a definitive answer, they are good questions. I think in this case there is a definitive answer.

Comment: @Bozho: There is no definitive answer to this.  It's going to be different depending on the application.  It even says in the question that it's debatable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - every new project should start using Java 7. Every recently-started project should upgrade to Java 7.

That's true for any framework (that is declared backward compatible) - use the newest version. If one goes out while developing - upgrade, if it's not too hard.

Comment: Also consider, that Java 6 will [EOL in July 2012](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html).

Comment: This is what i was thinking, but because java7 only got released, i'm thinking if its the right choice. its not a new project, but one that is not to hard to update to new java version. On the other hand, i dont want to find myself updated to a new build every month. So should i wait for the next few builds?

Comment: Unless you want your framework to be usable by people who have not already migrated.

Comment: +1 I agree, unless there are no issues. But Lucene and Solr + Java 7 was a showdown let us remember to be carefully with upgrading.

Comment: I was about to include the lucene example, but then I realized it can be solved by turning off the jvm setting that broke it. And I guess it will be fixed very soon.

Comment: Yes, but you have to know about. Still agree, but being careful isn't wrong. :)

Comment: "That's true for any framework btw" That was not the case with Python 3.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: clarification: that is declared backward-compatible